# Css removes when user clicks on date of datepicker

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an app in which we are highlighting dates in different colors by dynamically applying css and are using jquery mobile datepicker but when user click on any date the dynamically applied css got removed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to use your css with "!important" tag . DatePicker might change your css after selection.

Comment: we are using important tag in css but the class which is applied in datepicker library remains and the classes which are applied dynamically removes when user click on date